# Is there an equivalent to $.connection.hub.start().done() Javascript method for WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, signalr

I am developing a WPF chat application in there are two projects

1. WPF server
2. WPF client

While making a `login request`, I want user to get connected only if server is already started and if not user should not be able to login.

I'm using `SignalR` in  this application. How can I check if the server is already started before login, and then let user to connect to it.

It can be achievable in JavaScript with

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () 
{

});
```

How can I achieve this in wpf application?

Answer (score -1):

You can handle it through exceptions like the following code :

```
try
{
    var hubConnection = new HubConnection(url,...); 
    ... ; /*defining proxies and handlers*/
    hubConnection.Start().Wait();
} 
catch(Exception ex)
{ 
   /*handle exception code */
}
```

Alternatively : note that the 
`hubconnection.Start()` returns a `Task` so if you want to run a code and check if it's run successfully or there is an exception, you can use `ContinueWith` method:

```
 var hubConnection = new HubConnection(url,...); 
 ... ; /*defining proxies and handlers*/
 hubConnection.Start().ContinueWith( t=> {
                                           /* code to run if connection has been made successfully */
                                         },TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion );
```

So we can say this ContinueWith with the `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion` is the equivalent of $.connection.hub.start().done()

Comment: @ akazemis thanks for the quick response, but this is not what i m asking for. Actually these methods will get called if client connects to the server and what I want to know is how can I determine before letting user to connect if Server is started of not.

Comment: if you put this code in a try/catch you can catch exception in case of connection error, have you tried it ? :  `try{var hubConnection = new HubConnection(url,...); ... ; hubConnection.Start().Wait();} catch(Exception ex){ /*handle exception code */}`